# SocialEngine Mp3 Music Plugin generates a page saying The page you have attempted to access could not be found

Tags: download, mp3, socialengine

I recently purchased socialengine and YouNetco Mp3 music plugin. After the installation of the same everything was working just fine but the downloads of the songs.

whenever the download link is clicked a page generates stating

Page not found!
The page you have attempted to access could not be found.

SocialEngine and YouNetco both denies to and now not answering my tickets for solving this problem. each say to contact the other for solution.

The only thing that younetco said was "I have restored all files changed. Please contact with socialengine or godaddy (your hosting provider) for support.
Requirement: Can execute file http://www.shivamusic.tv/application/modules/Mp3music/externals/scripts/download.php"

Please help me regarding this issue I am really tensed and need this to work properly.

I shall be very thankful to you for the same.

Regards,

Preeti

Answer (score 0):

Preeti,

You need to check the user level setting for the download in your music plugin settings. Please share the admin member level setting for the download file. Hopefully you will be able to find the solution.